# DMA mode: burst or cycle stealing -- how to know and set? What is blocked?

Tags: cpu, memory-hardware, memory-access

What component and mechanism determines which DMA transfer mode is used?

How can be identified what DMA mode is used by a device, let's say on Linux?

Let's consider a contemporary AMD or Intel x86-64 system with two DMA PCIe devices.

Device 1 is an input device that regularly DMA writes for 300 microseconds (I'm guessing this one uses cycle stealing because the already updated data can be read while transfer is still ongoing?).

Device 2 is an output device that DMA reads for 100 microseconds.

The DMA memory regions of both devices do not overlap and are on separate pages.

If device 2 used burst mode, could this block the CPU from reading the DMA'd memory from device 1 (or any other memory) for 100 microseconds? Or could it even block the DMA from device 1 for 100 microseconds?